# Integration Apache camel(CXFRS) with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

My current project used Apache camel,I am working on creating route that should not use camel instead just use spring(with use of a controller)

Can someone point me to example which has camel routes but also have controller classes that use simple spring boot.

Comment: what is the connection between camel routes and controllers? you are comparing apples and oranges

Answer (score 0):

Please look into below link, which explain cxfrs with spring boot

https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter10/camel-cxf-rest-spring-boot